# Get only Image file name and path using phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap

How to get inside of mobile Image name and path names working Android and IOS both

Comment: Any one give idea Im new this phone gap Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the plugin "Device", you can access to the phone's information.

Install :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

Usage :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.cordova);
    console.log(device.model       );
    console.log(device.platform    );
    console.log(device.uuid        );
    console.log(device.version     );
    console.log(device.manufacturer);
    console.log(device.isVirtual   );
    console.log(device.serial      );
}
```

Source : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/